# How to transform an observable (A) that emits each second, into an observable that emits a list of elements by A each second

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-swift, reactive

Given an observable that emits strings every one second, I need another observable that gathers those elements and emits a full list each second.

```
func oneAtATime() -> Observable<String> {
    return Observable.create{ observable in
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let main = DispatchQueue.main

            for i in 0..<10 {

                sleep(1)

                main.async{
                    observable.onNext("Element\(i)")
                }
            }

            main.async{
                observable.onCompleted()
            }
        }

        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

This is what I have at the moment:

```
let oneEverySecond = oneAtATime()

var accEverySecond : Observable<[String]> = oneEverySecond.reduce([],accumulator: +)
```

Where + is a function that inserts an element in an array.

The problem is that I am seeing the full list of elements **only after completion. I am not receiving a new list every second.**

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, *.reduce()* fires only on completion. Simply replace it with *.scan()*, and it will fire on every upstream event.

And by the way, why not use *Observable.timer()* instead of a custom observable?

Answer (score 0):

```
Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  // Replace 1 second with your time if want to emit on other interval.
```

Above method can be used for frequent emission.